# How to open ports for Transmission?

Tags: bittorrent, transmission

I need to open port 51413 to speed up Transmission torrent. I tryed

```
sudo ufw allow 51413/tcp
```

and also

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT  -p tcp --dport 51413 -j ACCEPT
```

But they don't work (if I go to preferences to verify the port is still closed and if I use nmap it is the same). What can I do?

Comment: Do you use a router? If so: set the uPNP option and the same on the router. No need to mess with ports. I never ever had to use ufw for this. My transmission is on 6881, and it is shown as closed. Downloads come to me with several mbit per second (as in 10+).